# Como mudar a ordem de exibição do columns?

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte:

```css
.container{columns:3;}
span{width:100%;display:inline-block;width:100px;background-color:red;margin-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span style='height:20px'>1</span>
  <span style='height:50px'>2</span>
  <span style='height:30px'>3</span>
  <span style='height:50px'>4</span>
  <span style='height:50px'>5</span>
  <span style='height:20px'>6</span>
  <span style='height:30px'>7</span>
  <span style='height:25px'>8</span>
  <span style='height:35px'>9</span>
</div>
```

Ao executar o código acima, notem que a ordem de exibição dos números são verticais. Há alguma forma de mudar a ordem com CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso usando **display:flex**, com ele você consegue controlar a direção que serão exibidas as colunas através da propriedade **flex-direction:(row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse),** e caso queira controlar os itens você pode adicionar a propriedade **order** (que recebe um número inteiro), e definir uma ordem fixa.

Segue um exemplo usando o seu código:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <title>Teste</title>
    <style>
 .container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
  
 span {
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-bottom:10px
 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <span style='height:20px'>1</span>
  <span style='height:50px'>2</span>
  <span style='height:30px'>3</span>
  <span style='height:50px'>4</span>
  <span style='height:50px'>5</span>
  <span style='height:20px'>6</span>
  <span style='height:30px'>7</span>
  <span style='height:25px'>8</span>
  <span style='height:35px'>9</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Em Bootstrap 4**

https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#ordem

Mude a ordem visual de flex items, usando o utilitário order. 
Variações responsivas também são possíveis ***(ex.: .order-0, .order-1, .order-sm-0, .order-sm-1).***

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="order-3">Primeiro flex item</div>
  <div class="order-2">Segundo flex item</div>
  <div class="order-1">Terceiro flex item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pode fazer isso usando Bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
<div class='row'>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:20px'>1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:50px'>2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:30px'>3</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:50px'>4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:50px'>5</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:20px'>6</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:30px'>7</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:25px'>8</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <span style='height:35px'>9</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

para mais informaçoes leia a documentaçao de Boostrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/